# array from cell not continuos

Tags: arrays, excel, multidimensional-array, vba

create one array form one range is basic

```
dim arr as range
arr = range("A1:A10)
```

I test to creare one array from 2 range of cell using `UNION` but this function run only to modific cell proprierties non to paste the array in another range.
This is my exaple, col A is the value col B is the result.
[image]

My code:

```
Sub FuseRangeToArray()
    Dim ra As Range
    Dim rb As Range
    Dim rc As Range
    Dim a1 As Range
    Set ra = Range("A1:A10")     'the range is setting only for this exaple normally I pass it when I call my function
    Set rb = Range("A20:A29")    'idem
    Set rc = Union(ra, rb)
    rc.Select
    With Selection
        .Interior.Color = vbGreen
    End With
    Range("C1:C20") = rc.Value '20 is the count of all record, usually I use C:lastRow)

End Sub
```

I can to populate the array with loop of 2 range, but I looking for another way

Comment: It will be much simpler to paste area by area than anything else.

Comment: @Rory, sure and I know.
I want one array with alla record from 2 or more range, after  i can loop each item of this array to do my code.

Comment: It will still be easier to process each area as an array. There is no simple method I'm aware of to create one array from discontiguous ranges (for this **specific** example you could use a simple evaluate as the data is all in one column separated by blanks)

Comment: thank but is not that I search. I need one array with all record. I tryed also to set arr = range (ra,rb) and when I paste the array, the code paste correct from C1 to  C10, blanck cell from C11 to C19 , C20 with correct value.
to show all value I do change the output range to Range("C1:C30") to have 10 record, 10 blanck cell and the last 10 record.
I was convinced we couldn't do, I asked you to have a confirm. Thank

Comment: you will need to iterate through each cell in the range rc and insert them individually into the array.

Comment: @ScottCraner, ya, same I usually do, this is the unique way. tnk